MUnit test recorder is not working properly
Test recorder image I am facing multiple issues with the MUnit Test Recorder in Anypoint Studio while working on a Mule 4.6.7 project with Maven configuration (mule.maven.plugin.version 4.1.2, munit.version 3.2.1). The Test Recorder gets stuck on "Waiting for Data" even though the flow works correctly when executed normally. Additionally, a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException error occurs, potentially due to missing dependencies or compatibility issues. Could you assist with troubleshooting steps or configurations?
when i try to hit the recorder from postman i am getting this error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException
at com.mulesoft.mule.munit.recording.commons.wrappers.RecordedTypedValue.valueOf(RecordedTypedValue.java:101) ~[?:?]
at com.mulesoft.mule.munit.recording.commons.wrappers.RecordedMessage.(RecordedMessage.java:52) ~[?:?]
at com.mulesoft.mule.munit.recording.commons.wrappers.RecordedEvent.(RecordedEvent.java:53) ~[?:?]
at com.mulesoft.mule.munit.recording.server.RecordingInterceptor.createBefore(RecordingInterceptor.java:134) ~[?:?]
at com.mulesoft.mule.munit.recording.server.RecordingInterceptor.before(RecordingInterceptor.java:66) ~[?:?]
at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ProcessorInterceptorWrapper.before(ProcessorInterceptorWrapper.java:60)
enter image description here munit testrecorder is stuck

It is not enough information to reproduce the issue. [edit] your question to add a [mre].

Have you tried with the latest versions of the Mule Maven plugin, MUnit and Studio?

yes.I am using latest version only,as mentioned above.You can create small flow like this  
<http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="4edb4853-26f4-4c67-a5f8-e7dc1c78226d" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/test"/>

 then try to create munit using record test.I am using anypoint platform version 7.19

Edit the question to add details and versions. The question mentions older versions of some components. That's ambiguous. Be explicit.
